# Selenium - <select> suddenly becomes <input>

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

When I load a page manually in Chrome, the desired drop-down element is `<select>`, but when I `get()` this page using selenium chromedriver and inspect the page, this element is `<input>`, so I can't really manipulate it.

EDIT: if you want to reproduce my problem, here is the website https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jinwen

You need to pass in number 1 in the first input space on the left and press enter. The drop-down I want to manipulate goes by id "PaginalZiNum" (by default it is 20)

Comment: can't you manipulate an input tag with `.send_keys()`?

Comment: @AndrewRyan no, I get an ElementNotInteractableException with the following:
#16 0x55c2a3548588 <unknown>
#17 0x55c2a3548706 <unknown>
#18 0x55c2a35628b2 <unknown>
#19 0x7f775449cb43 <unknown>

Comment: Maybe they have the same attribute by which you are looking for the element?

Comment: @AndrewRyan added website url to reproduce my problem

Comment: Yes, they have the same name and id PaginalZiNum, you need to refine the search for the element.

Comment: you need to use xpath selector, two elements cannot have the same xpath, you can select the element and click on copy xpath in the browser